# SpringBoot 3.2.0-RC2 Non-resolvable parent POM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm going to try SpringBoot 3.2.0-RC2, this is my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0-RC2</version>
</parent>

<repositories>

    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

Not my project fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:example:0.0.1: 
Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.0-RC2 from/to repository.spring.milestone (http://repo.spring.io/milestone): 
Failed to transfer file: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.2.0-RC2/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.2.0-RC2.pom. 
Return code is: 405 , ReasonPhrase:Not Allowed. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the parent definition into this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0-RC2</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Also remove the entries for repositories because you are not allowed to access milestone repositories...

And furthermore remove the entry for central this is default by Maven no need to define that manually...

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestions and now the application fails with `Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.0-RC2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 6, column 13 -> [Help 2]`

Comment: Just try to build via `mvn clean verify -U`...

Comment: Now -  `Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.0-RC2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 6, column 13`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or in a corporate network?

Comment: no, without proxy. Looks like I found the reason - I have to use https://repo.spring.io/snapshot repo

Comment: Remove repo.spring.io in particular with SNAPSHOT's spring boot is available via central repository...